# MySQL does not use index based purely on amount of data

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I'm dealing with a seemingly odd case where simply the amount of data being returned from a MySQL query causes an obvious index to be used or not used.

We have a table called "items" with an indexed column called `type`.  Type is a tinyint(3), non-null value. The table is admittedly large both vertically and horizontally, and it does have a rather long list of singular indexes.

In many cases, selecting on this table while specifying `type` in the where field works as you'd expect, and indexes on the `type` field.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT item.itemid, item.`type` FROM item WHERE item.`type` IN (1,40);
```

works just fine, for instance.

```
SIMPLE  item    range   type    type    2   null    1634830 Using where; Using index
```

However, add one more unrelated return field, and suddenly it no longer uses the index.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT item.itemid, item.`type`,item.dir FROM item WHERE item.`type` IN (1,40);
```

```
1  SIMPLE  item    ALL type    null    null    null    3514503 Using where
```

The `dir` field isn't terribly interesting...it's just a boolean, and doesn't even have an index on it.  Using any other field has the same effect. Now, if I were to swap out another type of item for 40 - which I know has a lot of records - for a type that has fewer records, indexing once again works properly.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT item.itemid, item.`type`,item.dir FROM item WHERE item.`type` IN (1,2);
```

```
1  SIMPLE  item    range   type    type    2       79812   Using index condition
```

I realize that MySQL's optimizer isn't perfect, but it doesn't seem like this additional data should make the logic any different.

It's almost as if there's some kind of memory problem whereas the additional data isn't allow enough memory left for MySQL to do it's job.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try an `ANALYZE TABLE` on it to ensure it has the proper index cardinality, as doing an ALTER on the table may have confused things. I've not seen this particular behaviour though.

Comment: Thank @Leeft, analyze says it's ok
.item analyze status OK

Comment: It usually does. Does it make a difference for the query results though?

Comment: Oh you mean did that action change anything? No, the behavior is the same.

Comment: That's unfortunate, and yes, it'll rebuild index cardinality information. Only other thing I can think of to try is to add some dummy parameter to the query, something like `AND itemid > 0` (it might change the behaviour of the optimiser). Also, can you please update the question with the full table creation statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is behaving reasonably -- perhaps not optimally, but reasonably.

When faced with one of your queries, the optimizer has basically two choices.

First, it can scan the index to find the relevant records.  Then it may need to look up additional columns in the data pages (this is true of `dir`, it may also be true of `itemid` depending on whether it is declared as a primary index).

Second, it can scan the data pages, apply the `where` clause and pull the data that it needs directly from the data pages.

The balance between doing an index scan and then looking up information in the datapages versus simply scanning the data pages is a subtle one.  Small differences in the query might make one preferable to the other.

You can probably force index usage by creating a covering index.  Such an index contains all the columns of the query.  For these queries, that would be `type, itemid, dir`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this is the conclusion we're coming to too, though it still seems a bit hard to believe given the circumstances.  We'd rather not FORCE INDEX on this table and try to 'guess' this index on our own, but it looks like it may come to that.  Will give props if I don't hear anything better by tomorrow.